# C++ Dynamic_reconfigure client API in ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If we only implement dynamic_reconfigure in server side, we have to manually calibrate parameters in GUI. Calibrating parameters is tedious if we have a lot of parameters. I'm using ros `kinetic` to implement a client node in c++ that can subscribe to a topic `error` and dynamically calibrate parameters in server node based on the data from the subscription of the topic `error`. However, there is no c++ client API tutorial in official document. I can only look at the header file in [Github][1] for implementation, and I got the error for creating a client in my class. I want to implement a class `Calibration` to define my client node. The following is my implementation of client node and error message.

```
//in calibration.h
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/client.h>
#include <calibration/HcNodeConfig.h>

using namespace std;

class Calibration {
    hc::HcNodeConfig config;
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber listener;
    //dynamic_reconfigure::Client<hc::HcNodeConfig> adjuster("adjuster", &Calibration::adjuster_callback); 

    public:
        Calibration();
        void callback(const std_msgs::Float32ConstPtr& msg);
        void adjuster_callback(hc::HcNodeConfig& params);
};


//in calibration.cpp
#include "calibration.h"


void Calibration::adjuster_callback(hc::HcNodeConfig& params) {
    cout << "this is a dynamic_reconfigure callback" << endl;
}


void Calibration::callback(const std_msgs::Float32ConstPtr& msg) {
    float error = msg->data;
    dynamic_reconfigure::Client<hc::HcNodeConfig> client("hc", &Calibration::adjuster_callback, NULL);
    if (error <= 0.0) {
        config.direction = 0.0;
        client.setConfiguration(config);
    }

}


    Calibration::Calibration() {
        listener = n.subscribe("/error", 100, &Calibration::callback, this);
        ros::spin();
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "adjuster");
        Calibration cal();
        return 0;
    }
```

I got the following error.

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/dynamic_reconfigure/client.h: In instantiation of ‘dynamic_reconfigure::Client<ConfigType>::Client(const string&, boost::function<void(const ConfigType&)>, boost::function<void(const dynamic_reconfigure::ConfigDescription_<std::allocator<void> >&)>) [with ConfigType = hc::HcNodeConfig; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
/home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:11:100:   required from here
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/dynamic_reconfigure/client.h:332:19: warning: ‘dynamic_reconfigure::Client<hc::HcNodeConfig>::nh_’ will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
   ros::NodeHandle nh_;
                   ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/dynamic_reconfigure/client.h:326:8: warning:   ‘bool dynamic_reconfigure::Client<hc::HcNodeConfig>::received_configuration_’ [-Wreorder]
   bool received_configuration_;
        ^
In file included from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:5:0,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/dynamic_reconfigure/client.h:68:3: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
   Client(
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::function_void_mem_invoker1<MemberPtr, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with MemberPtr = void (Calibration::*)(hc::HcNodeConfig&); R = void; T0 = const hc::HcNodeConfig&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:940:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (Calibration::*)(hc::HcNodeConfig&); R = void; T0 = const hc::HcNodeConfig&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:728:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (Calibration::*)(hc::HcNodeConfig&); R = void; T0 = const hc::HcNodeConfig&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1077:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (Calibration::*)(hc::HcNodeConfig&); R = void; T0 = const hc::HcNodeConfig&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:11:100:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:231:28: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, Calibration, hc::HcNodeConfig&>) (const hc::HcNodeConfig&)’
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:163:7: note: candidate: R boost::_mfi::mf1<R, T, A1>::operator()(T*, A1) const [with R = void; T = Calibration; A1 = hc::HcNodeConfig&]
     R operator()(T * p, A1 a1) const
       ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:163:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:168:25: note: candidate: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf1<R, T, A1>::operator()(U&, A1) const [with U = U; R = void; T = Calibration; A1 = hc::HcNodeConfig&]
     template<class U> R operator()(U & u, A1 a1) const
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:168:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:231:28: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:176:25: note: candidate: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf1<R, T, A1>::operator()(const U&, A1) const [with U = U; R = void; T = Calibration; A1 = hc::HcNodeConfig&]
     template<class U> R operator()(U const & u, A1 a1) const
                         ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:176:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:231:28: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.h:1,
                 from /home/david-dev/workspace/lidar/src/calibration/src/online/calibration.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7: note: candidate: R boost::_mfi::mf1<R, T, A1>::operator()(T&, A1) const [with R = void; T = Calibration; A1 = hc::HcNodeConfig&]
     R operator()(T & t, A1 a1) const
       ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/calibration_calibration_node.dir/src/online/calibration.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/calibration_calibration_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think I pass wrong parameters to the `dynamic_reconfigure::Client` constructor. Any fix and improvement to my code? Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403654/c++-dynamic_reconfigure-client-api-in-ros/) by [hck007](https://answers.ros.org/users/96442/hck007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2022-07-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've met the similar problem before, this perhaps relates to "setting callback functions".

I tried following 2 methods,

1. not to add "&" for callback function and make it static member function.
2. use boost::bind, it may be like `dynamic_reconfigure_client_->setDescriptionCallback(boost::bind(&NameSpace::setDescriptionCallback, this, _1));`

both solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [RyanChen.YLC](https://answers.ros.org/users/99089/ryanchen.ylc/) with karma: 44 on 2022-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1